# depack/decrypt/extract/ application .bin files

Tags: c++, file, extract, unpack, bin

So I have an old dictionary on my pc, pretty old that I cannot find any track of it's developer or the website (I guess it hasnt even been released as an official software). I have a personal project of mine and I might need some of this words translated (about 200-300) and I see that inside the data folder that contains the database/list of files but Im unable to extract or read this files. Is there any way to extract or convert these .bin files to a text format or something readable.

So I'm thinking maybe this type of .bin files are not like .bin or .iso cd files that you can mount and read and these .BIN FILES are just to be used inside an application only.

Please help. This project is really highly important to me

Thank you alot.

Comment: bin files are binary, which means you can only convert them to text if you know exactly what all of the internal data structures.  Since it's a nonstandard format, that probably means that only the origional makers and the program itself can interpret those files.  It's like making up your own language, nobody else can understand it.  So no, nobody here can possibly help you with this.  Sorry :(

Comment: thanks for your response, yeah but it;s an old software and I cannot find the original developer, otherwise I would've found him, killed him and burry in a place no one could find lol (kidding).

Answer (score 1):

You can manually take a look at the files with a hex editor (here's a good free one: http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)  That might give you a clues as to what the data looks like.  You can also use the linux utility `strings` that will show you if there are human readable strings inside.

Otherwise, you're basically out of luck.  There is no .bin file format, it's just whatever proprietary data format the software developers chose.  So you won't be able to use some standard off the shelf converter.  You can try to reverse engineer, but that will probably be hard and require you to write your own utilities.

Comment: Hello yes I've downloaded it and I see a bunch of binary numbers 0 1 etc :) and there's another colon on the right that displays random characters. Do I have any chance? What about reverse engineering, can you show me some reference links?
Thanks

Comment: If you see random characters on the right, and nothing readable, then you're pretty much hosed.  Sorry :(